# Changing widget's name in both design view and code view in Qt

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I'm just starting Qt5 using QtCreator, and I have a question regarding changing the name of widgets in `design` view.

So, for example, I have a [`QComboBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) and I I use [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qobject.html#findChild) to find it (this is in `mainwindow.cpp`):

```
QComboBox *comboBoxType;
void MainWindow::on_Start_clicked()
{

    comboBoxType = ui->stackedWidget->findChild<QComboBox *>("typeComboBox", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    comboBoxType->addItem("Hash");
    comboBoxType->addItem("Hash2");
}
```

But when I changed the name of the the widget from `typeComboBox` to `typeBox` in `design` view, for instance, the `typeComboBox` name in `mainwindow.cpp` wasn't changed, and led to an obvious crash:

```
02:32:37: The program has unexpectedly finished.
02:32:37: The process was ended forcefully.
02:32:37: D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe crashed.
```

Is there any ways of changing/updating both name, in `.ui` and `mainwindow.cpp` simultaneously, or is there a better way other than manually typing in the name in `mainwindow.cpp`, so that I don't have to go find the culprit in code after I change something in `design` view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QtCreator you can use the Advanced Find menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to do a find and replace operation across all files in the project.

Enable the options "Case sensitive" and "Whole words only" to limit the match to the exact name.